# get_posts with meta query for a user relation (ACF) not returning any result

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type **fvc_members**

Using advanced custom fields I've added a new field called **user** which is a relation object to an existing user.

I have the following code to query for the posts where the current user is set as **user**

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'fvc_members',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'user',
            'value'     => '"' . get_current_user_id() . '"',
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    )
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

I've tried differnt options to write the value ( wrapped in '', wrapped in "", wihtout wrap, compare with LIKE ), however I can't find a way to get this working

Comment: Are you sure `get_current_user_id()` is not empty or null? Have you tried assigning it to a variable `$mCurrentUserId = get_current_user_id()` before the `$args` and then `value => $mCurrentUserID`?

Comment: Try this -> `$args = array(
                      'numberposts' => 5,
                      'post_type' => 'fvc_members',
                      'meta_query' => array(
                          array(
                              'meta_key'       => 'user',
                              'meta_value'     => get_current_user_id(),
                          )
                      )
                  );`

Comment: I output get_current_user_id() and i receive what i expect

Comment: Also try what you have, but without using `compare`

Comment: that's working! thanks - feel free to post it as full answer

Comment: The first one with the `$args` or the second one without the `compare`? No problem!

Comment: second one without compare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$args` without using the `compare` statement. You only need the key and the value which that makes it automatically a "compare" statement :

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'fvc_members',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'user',
            'value'     => '"' . get_current_user_id() . '"',
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

> If `user`  has only single integer value then you dont need the
>   inverted comma, and also add the compare type.

Here is the code:

```
$args = [
    //...
    //...
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'user',
            'value' => get_current_user_id(),
            'compare' => '=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC' //<-- add this
        ]
    ]
];
//...
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Reference: [Custom Field Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Hope this helps!